# excel pivot-table compute subtotal using dax

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax

I am struggling with a "simple" function that is killing me. I am simply trying to get the subtotal of each group in a pivot table. I d like to compute the percentage of each subgroup as my input data are wrong. It seems I cannot do the classic EARLIER, and there is no this or current or whatever...

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( table1[numbers] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( table1 ),
        table1[Names] = FIRSTNONBLANK ( ALL ( table1[Names] ), tables[Names] )
    )
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Absolutely counterintuitive to me, but it works...

```
=CALCULATE (
   SUM ( table1[numbers] ),
   ALLEXCEPT ( table1, table1[Names])
)
```